# How to upgrade NuGet package lucene-net from version 3.0.3 to version 4.8.0

Tags: upgrade, lucene.net, nuget-package

I am using `lucene-net` version 3.0.3, and I want binary filed store. Binary filed requires lucene-net version 4, but I cannot install this version.

This is what I have tried and the error I received:

> ```
> PM> Install-Package Lucene.Net -Version 4.8.0.648-beta
>
> Install-Package:
> Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need
> to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the
> packages before performing any operations.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Install-Package Lucene.Net -Version 4.8.0.648-beta
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
> ```

Answer (score 2):

As said in [this blogpost](http://code972.com/blog/2016/07/98-lucene-net-4-8-is-in-beta-and-we-need-your-help%20%22this%20blogpost) of Itamar Syn-Hershko, Lucene.NET version 4.8 is not yet available with NuGet.

But as described, you can get it through the private feed of MyGet though. To do this, first add a new package source in the NuGet Package Manager settings, with Source: https://www.myget.org/F/lucene-net/.

After you've done this, you should find the new version with the NuGet Package Manager (don't forget to set the correct Package source).